# fixed background image in BlackBerry z10 JQM

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, blackberry-10

I inserted a background image using CSS in jquery mobile. This is the codes I used:

```
.ui-page {
background: transparent url(images/bg.png);
background-attachment:fixed;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

But this code doesn't work when deployed to the device.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong what did I lack?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply so you might have already found out the answer...

You need to use a full URL for images on the crapberry.

```
background-image:url('http://example.com/images/bg.png');
```

Rather than what you've used above

Hope this helps anyone else having this problem